# Azure IoT Storage bind to device local storage

Tags: linux, azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I would like to achieve "[Give modules access to a device's local storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module)". I tried almost every scenario, still couldn't get the data from the module to the host.

In module, all data is stored in /app location. I tried binding /app to host location /etc/iotedge, Also tried binding lots of scenario, it every time creates a 'edgeHub' folder and stores .sst files and logs, so I'm sure its initiating the bind, But why does the data doesn't appear in the host machine? Data are image .jpg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recommend not to bind folder under /etc/iotedge folder. For example bind under home folder.
2. Recommend not to bind /app inside the container as I believe some application runtime or exe is in that folder. It is good to use another folder.
3. You need to use docker mount instead of docker volume.
4. Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob

Comment: 1. Ok, So i need to bind /home in the host machine, and not /etc/iotedge. 2. Here, all data is stored in /app, so I need to bind this location as modulestorepath isn't it, only then data will be retained to the binded to hoststorepath location isn't it?

Comment: 4. Also I'm not using this reference at all, not local blob, I'm using the above link I mentioned in the q, it's just binding the location